# Image entry in a category template

Tags: assets, category

I'm running into an issue here, hopefully someone can shed some light. 
I'm in a news category template,

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category) %} 
  {% for image in news.newsimage %}
    <a href="{{ news.url }}"><img alt="{{ news.title }}" src="{{ news.url }}" /></a>
  {% endfor %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

My entry.title, date, etc. all output correctly, I can't figure out how to output the image asset associated with newsimage.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to access a `news` variable that probably doesn't exist.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category) %} 

    {# Your image field will be found on your `entry` variable (not a `news` variable) #}
    {% for image in entry.newsimage %}

        {# One you are looping through your image field, 
           you can access the image properties via the `image` 
           variable you defined in your loop #}
        <a href="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
          <img alt="{{ image.title }}" src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" />
        </a>

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

If you only have a single news image, you can grab that image directly using the `first()` method, instead of looping through your image field:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category) %} 

    {% set image = entry.newsimage.first() %}

    {% if image %}
        <a href="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
          <img alt="{{ image.title }}" src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" />
        </a>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank makes complete sense...
Thank you so much Ben..